# PayPal recurring payments negative testing

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am trying to use the Recurring payment API offered by PayPal.

When I create a recurring payment either with express chekout token or with credit card details the payment is always successful.

There are instructions here on how to test error conditions http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_error_conditions.html
 i.e. you can specify for example cvv2=116 and it will produce an error for doDirectPayment, but it does not seem to work with recurring payments.

Is there a way to simulate failed recurring payment in sandbox?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck? Any tips for those that follow in your footsteps?

Comment: For those who follow in my footsteps: there is Payflow Pro Recurring Billing guide [link](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf), you can find "Testing Recurring Billing" section there. "One can use the amount of the transaction to generate a particular result value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who follow in my footsteps: there is Payflow Pro Recurring Billing guide [here](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf), you can find "Testing Recurring Billing" section there. "One can use the amount of the transaction to generate a particular result value".

Comment: I can find the section but not the text you quote from that section. Has it changed?